# How to change the lock screen clock to a message Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen

I'm curious to know if you can change the lock screen from having a lock to a message that says something like "I'm watching you" or "Hello there" on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. 
I've done a good bit of googling but I wasn't able to find any resources about it.

Comment: you mean in place of time & date you want to put your msg?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZCQY.gif are you looking for something like this?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcYnM.gif or something like this?

Comment: Yea thats exactly what i'm looking for